# FullCalendar Horizontal Time Range Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Can someone tell me how to achieve something like below image.
How can I select particular time range in selected days.

Notice that the selection spans multiple days. It's a horizontal selection across multiple days (as opposed to a continuous one).

I am using fullCalendar jquery library.

[image: intended result]

Comment: You have examples **[here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks for your response. But there is no example to select particular time range in all the day.Please check event begins from 7:15 to 9:15 . which is marked in red color.

Comment: @user3796642 Have you tried inspecting [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) ? You can get what is selected.

Comment: @lbrahim thanks for giving suggesion. actually i cannot able to select horizontally.

Comment: Yeah, I've been following fullcalendar on SO for a while and I've never seen this implemented. It requires a rather custom solution. I'll see if I have time to give it a try.

Comment: @slicedtoad great.. Please try to provide a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the exact thing you need to do isn't quite possible unless you want to heavily modify FC. But you can do something quite close:

[image: horizontal FC selection]

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/owd804hd/8/)

### Basic Algorithm

- Turn on [`selectHelper`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectHelper/) so that FC will attempt to render it as an event.
- In [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/), stop the helper from actually rendering. Instead, take its start and end dates and chunk them into one event per day.
- Render the chunked events.

### Chunking and Rendering

```
// Chunks a multiday event into an array of events
// i.e. From {start:"2015-05-06T11:00",end:"2015-05-08T15:00"}
//      into [ {start:"2015-05-06T11:00",end:"2015-05-07T15:00"},
//             {start:"2015-05-07T11:00",end:"2015-05-08T15:00"} ]
var chunk = function (event,type) {
    var chunked = [];
        //diff = moment.duration(event.end.diff(event.start));
    if (event.start.format('HHmm') > event.end.format('HHmm')) {
        return false; //Can't chunk, starttime > endtime
    }
    for (var day = event.start.clone(); !day.isAfter(event.end,'day'); day.add(1,'day')) {
        chunked.push({
            start:day.clone(),
            end:day.clone().hour(event.end.hour()).minute(event.end.minute()),
            id:"chunked-"+type //Used as a flag in the render function
        })
    }
    return chunked;
};
// Takes an event and renders it chunked. Also remove the previous chunked-helper.
// Runs after a timeout and only once.
var renderChunkedHelper = (function(){
    var id = 0;
    return function(event){
        window.clearTimeout(id);
        id = window.setTimeout(function(){
            var chunked = chunk(event,"helper");
            eventToChunk = null;
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( "removeEvents", "chunked-helper");
            for(var i = 0; i < chunked.length; i++){
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", chunked[i]); //Manually render each chunk
            }
        },0); //delay in ms. Could be tweaked for optimal perfomance

    }
})();
```

### FC options

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    /*...*/
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function( start, end, jsEvent, view ){
        if(window.confirm("Create this event?")){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( "removeEvents", "chunked-helper");
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( "addEventSource",chunk({start:start,end:end},"event"));
        }else{
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( "removeEvents", "chunked-helper");
        }
    },
    eventRender: function (event,element) {
        if(event.className[0] === "fc-helper"){ //if it's the drag event
            renderChunkedHelper(event);
            return false; //don't actually render the select helper
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please check the issue,i cannot able to select the last day of the week.

Comment: @user3796642 there, it's fixed. In `chunk`, the condition `day.isBefore(event.end,'day');` is now `!day.isAfter(event.end,'day')`. Basically, I was checking less than (<) when I needed to be checking less  than or equal to (<=).

Comment: thanks lot for sharing your skill. It would be great if you can solve two more issue. I couldnt able to select the time range when i enable selectOverlap: false. Dont mind for requesting too many things.

Comment: Hey, I tried to adapt this for resourceDayView, but couldn't get it work. Do you have any idea if it is possible?

Comment: @movsky That would be a rather different operation, no? Essentially, every row you drag downwards would be booking a new resource. The above allows you to turn a range selection into multiple "chunks". Given that you can't even create resource bookings by clicking and dragging yet... What you want to do isn't trivial.

Comment: Can you write same function for 3.x?

Comment: thanks @slicedtoad, but any way to make it work on version 3?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same requirement recently. After digging on the Internet, no perfect solution was found. The above solution resolved the rendering problem but
has some other issues, e.g. dragging issue, event ID.

So I forked the original fullCalendar repo on github and extended it with horizontal selection support.

[DEMO](https://deepskyr.github.io/)

Usage:

Please replace the js file and set options as below:

(expandThrough is added. false means horizontal selection is on)

```
...
selectable: true,
selectOverlap: false,
eventOverlap: false,
editable: true,
expandThrough: false,
...
```

Javascript dist file:

https://github.com/deepskyr/fullcalendar/blob/horizontal_range_selection/dist/fullcalendar.js

Comment: Hi @deepsky, did you upgrade for 3.x this fork repo? I tried your changes on my calendar, but it is not working. If you have a little bit time; can you modify for 3.x?